# Selecting all vertices of an equilateral triangle, one by one, always results in an oriented, almost circular path. Why?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, graph-theory, triangles, directed-graphs

*Perhaps there is some simple explanation here. I couldn't find any, especially since the old problem of inscribing an equilateral triangle in a circle flooded every search engine. Therefore, if this is a duplicate in any way, please forgive me.*

Suppose you have an equilateral triangle with vertices ${\rm red}$, ${\rm green}$, and ${\rm blue}$. By brute force, it is easy to see that, no matter where we start - say ${\rm red}$ WLOG - if we select the vertices one at a time until there is none left, then we end up going in an oriented path that is as if we traced a circle, starting at ${\rm red}$, that intersects each vertex; we have either

$${\rm red}\to{\rm green}\to{\rm blue}$$

or

$${\rm red}\to{\rm blue}\to{\rm green}.$$

Why?

It seems strange to me, given that the dihedral group $D_3$ of symmetries of an equilateral triangle is the smallest nonabelian group. True: not all of that group is used, so the symmetries at hand correspond to the group $\Bbb Z_3$, which *is* abelian; but then again the same problem for an $n$-gon for $n>3$ - that of selecting vertices one by one until all are taken - does not always lead to a "circular motion" (so to speak),${}^\dagger$ whereas $\Bbb Z_n$ is abelian.

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: Just start with a vertex, say $v$, then go to an adjacent vertex, then go to the other vertex adjacent to $v$, so that, no matter what happens next, the motion of selecting vertices is not circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by your statement that "not all of that group is used". In fact, the full group of symmetries of the 3 element set $\{{\rm R},{\rm B},{\rm G}\}$ is used, this is the symmetric group $S_3$, which is coincidentally isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_3$, so all of the group $D_3$ is also used. The elements of $S_3\approx D_3$ may be listed as

$${\rm RGB, GBR, BRG, RBG, BGR, GRB}.$$

The same problem for an $n$-gon with $n>3$ has a different outcome, because the symmetric group $S_n$ and the dihedral group $D_n$ have different orders: $n! > 2n$ when $n > 3$; arbitrary permutations correspond to $S_n$; and permutations that come from going around the vertices on the $n$-gon in one direction or the other, one at a time, correspond to $D_n$.

Comment: I guess I confused myself by the WLOG part, hence the "not all of that group" statement. Thank you for this answer.